# Precision digits in Log[]

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

Why does

`N[Log[10, 6613], 20]` give the requested 20 digits of precision

(* $3.8203985227039816648$ *)

but

`N[Log[10, 6613.3], 20]` does not?

(* $3.82042$ *)

The documentation for `Log` states:

"The precision of the output tracks the precision of the input" so one might expect more digits in the output for the latter case.

Comment: In addition to what sacratus said: `Log[10, 6613.3]` immediately evaluates to `3.82042`, then `N[..., 20]` is applied only afterwards.  `N` won't influence the calculation of the logarithm.  Try ``Log[10, 6613.3`20]``.  This also evaluates immediately, but since it starts with an arbitrary precision (not machine precision) number, precision tracking kicks in.  Thus the result will not have a precision of exactly 20, but it will be close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe

In:

```
Precision[6613]
```

Out:

```
Infinity
```

In:

```
Precision[6613.3]
```

Out:

```
MachinePrecision
```

The first number is an integer and has infinite precision the second number is a numerical value that is represented with a finite precision.